# How customize flash components?

Tags: flash, actionscript, slider, scrollbar, customization

How create and set template for default flash compenent (slider and scrollbar)?

Default example:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can skin the built-in components with CSS. Check the following docs for more info:

- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=skinning_2.html
- http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/05/designer_scroll.html

Example for the ScrollBar skin:

```
ScrollBar {
  up-arrow-skin: ClassReference(null);
  down-arrow-skin: ClassReference(null);
  trackSkin: Embed(source="skins/ScrollBarTrack.png", scaleGridLeft="1", scaleGridTop="4", scaleGridRight="5", scaleGridBottom="16");
  thumbUpSkin: Embed(source="skins/ScrollBarThumb_up.png", scaleGridLeft="1", scaleGridTop="4", scaleGridRight="5", scaleGridBottom="16");
  thumbOverSkin: Embed(source="skins/ScrollBarThumb_over.png", scaleGridLeft="1",     scaleGridTop="4", scaleGridRight="5", scaleGridBottom="16");
  thumbDownSkin: Embed(source="skins/ScrollBarThumb_down.png", scaleGridLeft="1",         scaleGridTop="4", scaleGridRight="5", scaleGridBottom="16");
}
```